# Express GET request not working after adding authentication

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

I'm stuck on this very simple problem and I don't know what I am doing wrong. I'm creating a simple `RESTAPI` with users and authentication. This is the GET request that I'm trying to run:

```
router.get('/users/me',auth ,async(req,res)=>{
console.log(req.user)
console.log('Entered the get request')
res.send(getUserData(req.user)) })
```

Basically, at the end of the authentication, I save the user fetched from the database into `req.user` object and then I send it to the client using `res.send(req.user)`. As you can see in the code below:

```
const auth = async(req,res,next)=>{
try{
    const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ','')
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token,'secretkey')
    
    const db = req.app.locals.database
    const user = await db.collection('users').findOne({
        _id: decoded.id,
        'tokens.token':token
    })
    console.log(user)
    
    if(!user){
        throw new Error()
    }
    req.user = user 
    next()

}catch(e){
    res.status(401).send('Please Authenticate')
}}
```

The problem is that this authentication function is working perfectly fine. I have used it on other routes as well. But in this `GET` request, the authentication function runs (I identified this using many console logs) and fetches the data correctly. But it doesn't enter the get request once the middleware(auth function) has completed the call.
From POSTMAN, when I send `GET` requests, I get a `404 error` and I have no idea why. I have literally spent hours trying to make sense of this. Please help me out if you know what might be the problem.

EDIT: So I was able to run the get request by moving the request above the following request that I also have in the same file:

```
router.get('/users/:id',auth ,async(req,res)=>{

const id = req.params.id
const db = req.app.locals.database
try{
    
    const result = await db.collection('users').findOne({_id: id})
    const userData = getUserData(result)
    res.status(200).send(userData)
    
}catch(e){
    res.status(404).send()
}
```

})

But now this request doesn't work. I cant figure out what positioning has to do with requests functionality. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Have you tried to move the `next()` call, from the `try` block, to a `finaly` block? Perhaps, you throw there a error, then your `next` call is never reached

Comment: Can you add the logs?

Comment: I dont think its a problem with next() call. As I said, this same auth is being used in another route too. And that works.